# Yahoo Messenger servers for use in API

Tags: c#, tcpclient, yahoo-api

I'm making a C# Wrapper for Yahoo IM API. Sometimes when I'm using the server `developer.messenger.yahoo.com`, it gave me errors (`4xx or 5xx`).

After hours searching on the web, I found this link `https://help.yahoo.com/kb/SLN1227.html`. The link contains information about `Yahoo Messenger Servers, Port and Protocols`.

I want to know can I use these servers to replace `developer.messenger.yahooapis.com` server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the link you've posted, the configurations are supposed to be used by the IM client itself, not to use with the API.

So, probably they'll **NOT** work.

Comment: I'm not using the IM API (I'm using the Contacts API), but I face some `4xx` and `5xx` errors sporadically too. Basically, you have to deal with them, maybe display a friendly message to the user, wait a bit and try again.

Answer (score 1):

In this [link](https://developer.yahoo.com/messenger/guide/ch02.html) appear a different server: **developer.messenger.yahooapis.com**

Be aware that 4xx errors means that the request was malformed (problem in your side, be sure your code it´s correct) while 5xx errors means that there is a internal error in the server.

Comment: Sorry, I mistyped the host address. And thanks for your extra info!